# Spring @Transaction not working for JPA and Webservice

Tags: web-services, spring

I have a code where I am updating one database through JPA and updating 1 more database through webservice. But If I am getting some exception from webservcie my JPA transaction is not getting rollback. Can you please suggest me how to make JPA + Webservice work as XA Transaction

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">

</bean>
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/persistenceUnit"/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And my java class looks like below

```
@Transactional
public void method1()
{

// persist database1 through JPA

// persist database2 through Webservice
}
```

Comment: I don't think any web service stack is XA-aware. Why your spring transaction is not rolled back can probably be explained by the code of the method, that you don't show.

Answer (score 1):

What type of exception is the web service call throwing?

The default behavior is rollback for RuntimeExceptions, so if the ws is throwing a checked exception there will be no rollback, although you can change that with:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I was assuming rollback will be done for both checked and unchecked exceptions.